# Add Noindex Tag SEO Sitemao - Both Category and Product

Tags: magento-1.7, product, category, seo, sitemaps

How do i add noindex to the catalog/seo_sitemap in Magento

Both catalog/seo_sitemap/product/ and catalog/seo_sitemap/category

We have a large store and resulted in about 100 useless pages in google.

We still want it to be crawled but have noindex tag on the pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following snippet:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,FOLLOW</value></action>
</reference>
```

In your case, that needs to be inserted in the `catalog_seo_sitemap` layout handle.

Answer (score 1):

you can add with `local.xml` code for category and product

for **product detail page**

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW</value></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

**category page**

```
<catalog_category_layered>
 <reference name="head">
            <action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW</value></action>
        </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>

<catalog_category_default>
     <reference name="head">
                <action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW</value></action>
            </reference>

</catalog_category_default>
```

hope this will work for you